# Issue while generating pdf using itext

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I am trying to create a `PDF` using `itext` and here is the code I am using.

```
String test = "I will have a huge contents here ";
String baseUrl = "C:/Image.png";
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setDocumentFromString(test, baseUrl);
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(stream);

return Response
            .ok(stream.toByteArray())
            .header("content-disposition",
                     "attachment; filename = export.pdf").build();
```

This `code` is creating a blank `PDF` with no content.

Comment: what is the variable stream ?

Comment: i have updated the stream in my question

Comment: String baseUrl = "C:/Image.png"; is not a correct baseUrl, because it is not a folder... try: renderer.setDocumentFromString(test);

Comment: I have an image in the html, So when i use setDocumentFromString(test), pdf is getting generated without image .

Comment: Not sure but should `"<html><body>....</body></html>"` not be needed?